# cannot find database server on client machine

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

For the past week I've been trying to create a setup of my windows application.

I have created a Windows application and I want to install that on client machine. For that I have added Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Express in prerequisites while creating setup project.

Now in order to install my database schema that is creating database and tables on client machine, I have created one installer class in project and added one custom action refrenced from [installer class steps](http://techbrij.com/145/install-sql-server-database-with-visual-studio-setup)

This is my connection string

```
Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True
```

But I'm only getting this error:

> *System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not
>   found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct
>   and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.
>   (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a
>   connection to SQL Server)*
>
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning()
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo, SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean
>   ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, Boolean encrypt, Boolean
>   trustServerCert, Boolean integratedSecurity)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo
>   serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout,
>   TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnection owningObject)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo
>   serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance,
>   SqlConnection owningObject, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions,
>   TimeoutTimer timeout)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(SqlConnection
>   owningObject, TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString
>   connectionOptions, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
>
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity
>   identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Object providerInfo,
>   String newPassword, SqlConnection owningObject, Boolean
>   redirectedUserInstance)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions
>   options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool,
>   DbConnection owningConnection)
>   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnectionOptions options)
>
> at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection
>   owningObject)
>   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection
>   owningObject)
>   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.GetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningObject)
>   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection)
>   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
>   at WindowsFormsApplication5.Installer1.ExecuteSql(String serverName, String dbName, String Sql)

Changing Data source to `.\SQLEXPRESS` causes this error:

> *System.InvalidOperationException: Instance failure.*
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo, SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean
>   ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, Boolean encrypt, Boolean
>   trustServerCert, Boolean integratedSecurity)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo
>   serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout,
>   TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnection owningObject)

**Note : I am getting this error while executing script which installs the schema of my database..**

I just want to install my Windows database application to client machine. As I am already lacking in time, any other suggestions are also welcome...

Regards,
Mahesh

Comment: A SQL Express instance is usually called .\SQLExpress, i.e. change your connections string to 'Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;...'

Comment: @nonnb see my modified question as it also gives me the error

Comment: So, what is the question? You can't connect to your database, I assume Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Express is installed, since it is in your prerequisites. Is the SQL service running?

Comment: why don't you try attach the `.mdf` in the custom action to the instance , instead of schema execution?

Comment: .\SQLEXPRESS has a backslash, not a slash

Comment: `./SQLEXPRESS` and `.\SQLExpress` is diff.Use second one.

Comment: @Furqan I tried that way but was getting sql version error as from my dev machine it was creating mdf file of sql 2008 R2 and on my client machine it is sql 2008.. can u provide full solution for that way..

Comment: @MarkPattison i have used correct one..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True
```

Comment: try using double slash http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CommentView.aspx?guid=89c01cae-e045-4b06-bff1-8dd2d596e266

Comment: I have entered the server name through dialog box.. So by adding .\SQLEXPRESS.. it automatically takes double slash.. below is my connection string "Data Source=.\\SQLExpress;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"

Comment: check the user with which you have logged in have proper rights in SQL...try giving it sysadmin rights